# jQuery Create Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'd like to create a callback on a simple function.

I have this function which is called on button click:

```
function main(){ };
```

So I'd like `main()`, when its done to call this:

```
 function test(){ }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the main() function not use ajax,you can use：

```
function main(callback) {
    // ... do your thing
    callback();
}

function test(){}

eg:
<input type="button" onclick="main(test);"/>
```

if the main() function use ajax,you can call test() in complete function like this:

```
function main(callback){
    $.ajax({
        ...
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus){
            callback(); 
        },
        ...
    });
}

function test(){
    ...
}
eg:
<input type="button" onclick="main(test);" value="test"/>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks. I am not using ajax. On your first example, the API doesn't allow me to call main(test). Example: API.loadAndWait('snippet', '5', main); so if I replace the main with main(test) it doesnt compile

Comment: In that case you would have to use something like `API.loadAndWait('snippet', '5', function() {main(test);});`

Answer (score 4):

```
function main(callback) {
    // ... do your thing
    callback();
}

main(function(){
    alert('this is the callback speaking');
});
```

Comment: @jQuerybeast: You pass your `test` function as the `callback` parameter of `main`. Updated my answer with more details

Answer (score 1):

As i understood its simple,Sorry if i am not in the point.

```
function main() {
// ... do your thing
test();
}


function test() {
// ... do your thing in test

}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but test is executed with the main

Comment: So whats the deference?If you want to execute test after the main this is it.Or if you want to call test few minutes after main use setTimeout("test()",3000); .Then it will be called after 3000 milliseconds.

Comment: Not when you only execute `test()` after(!) you did whatever you have to do in main(). We don't know your code so we cannot guess where in your code you'll have to place the call to `test()`. Show us more code an we can help you