# getJSON within ajax call causing infinite loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I am currently calling external php files and displaying them within specific div.  This is all done using the standard jQuery $.ajax call.

However an issue arises when one of the pages being pulled in attempts the following getJSON call, resulting in an infinite loop:

```
function getContacts() {
  if ($('body.all-contacts').length){
    $.getJSON('assets/data/contacts.json', function(data) {
      var template = $('#contacts-template').html();
      var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
      $('.contact-list').html(info);
    });
  }
};
```

The above function is called as follows:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
....
getContacts();
....
})
```

I've also tried using ajaxStop() instead of ajaxComplete() but the issue persists.

Comment: You're launching an ajax call when an ajax call completes. The infinite loop looks logical.

Comment: why are you calling `getContacts()` inside `ajaxComplete`

Comment: During the initial ajax call (to load the external pages) the body class name is updated, upon completion of this I need to trigger the getContacts function as that needs to act on the newly loaded external page.

Comment: Try to use a callback instead of `ajaxComplete()`. For instance, create a function `setUp()` that wil load all your external files. Once setUp() is finished, call `getContacts()`. (create a callback : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516191/jquery-create-callback )

Comment: Thanks so much everyone, a callback was exactly what was need rather than ajaxComplete!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite loop seems normal to me. Since you call the function getContacts when the getJSON is completed, getContacts contains the getJSON call so the call will fire again, which will result in another ajaxcomplete callback, which will fire the getContacts function again. etc etc.

To **prevent** this from happening you can remove the getContacts() in the ajaxcomplete function.

If you wish to keep the infinite loop but with **time intervals** between every ajax call you can use the javascript function setTimeout. format of function:
`setTimeout("javascript function",milliseconds);`

Comment: Thanks Kevin, as mentioned above, the callback was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`getContacts()` should not be called, when a `getContacts()` call completes.

If you need to call that function, when another one completes, make sure (using `if ...`) that it is not `getContacts()` that completed.

Comment: How do I prevent it being triggered again by the same function? Do i need to avoid firing it only in the event that the last ajax call made was getContacts() ?

Comment: No. You need to make certain, that once the ajaxcomplete is called, no case can arise where you step into the `getContacts` section again. For example, you if call `xyz()` completes and triggers the   `getContacts()` call, you have to make sure that this doesn't trigger `xyz()`. That goes for any number of chained calls. Good luck.